# Zed-Graph Set scale to default programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

I've got a winforms application which uses zed-graph library to plot graphs. When I right-click on the control (while application is running) a context menu shows up and I can choose `Set Scale to default`.
How do I achive this `Set Scale to default`-behaviour programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each x- and y-axis following code is executed:

```
_scale._minAuto = true;
_scale._maxAuto = true;
_scale._majorStepAuto = true;
_scale._minorStepAuto = true;
_crossAuto = true;
_scale._magAuto = true;
_scale._formatAuto = true;
```

For more information easily look in the source code and search for "Set Scale to default".

Comment: Fanou's comment: "The answer is not complete, you have to call the AxisChange() methode of your zedgraph component."

Comment: [`RestoreScale`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_ZedGraphControl_RestoreScale.htm) docs.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2014, I couldn't get the above solution to work in VS2008, C#.  But I succeeded doing the following:

```
    private void frmGraph_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZGraphComponent.RestoreScale(ZGraph.GraphPane);
    }
```

In the "VisibleChanged" event handler for the window containing the graph component, I call the "RestoreScale" method on the graph component, passing the main graph pane as the argument.